# Why do I still get an error when trying to convert varchar to int?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert this data in my database to int based off the code below from another thread. As I'm pretty new to SQL I just wanted to try and convert the column "Web ID" to understand the code and not have too many errors.

[image: database contents]

I'm using the following code, but still get an error:

```
select * 
into #tmp 
from [db].[desktop-order-data]

truncate table [db].[desktop-order-data]

alter table [db].[desktop-order-data] 
    alter column ["Web ID)"] int

insert [db].[desktop-order-data]
    select cast(["Web ID"] as int)
    from #tmp

drop table #tmp
```

When I run this, I get this error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I'm a bit confused as I'm still referencing the same table as in the query. What should I be referencing here?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your sample code has multiple statements.  Which one causes the error?

Comment: You create a table using `select`/`into` with four columns, then use an `insert` with a single column. Curious thing, that. Are there really quotation marks (") in the data? Aside: Have you checked the range of [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Answer (score 3):

You should simply be able to do:

```
alter table [db].[desktop-order-data] alter column ["Web ID"] int;
```

For your code, you want an `update`, not an `insert`.  You don't need a temporary table.  Just do:

```
update [db].[desktop-order-data]
    set ["Web ID"] = cast(["Web ID"] as int);
```

If this causes a problem, then find the rows that don't convert.  In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select d.*
from [db].[desktop-order-data] d
where try_cast(["Web ID"] as int) is null and ["Web ID"] is not null;
```

If you actually have double quotes around the values, then you need to remove them.  I would recommend:

```
-- remove double quotes
update [db].[desktop-order-data] d
    set ["Web ID"] = replace(["Web ID"], '"', '');

-- check that the resulting values are convertible
select *
from db].[desktop-order-data] d
where try_cast(["Web ID"] as int) is null and ["Web ID"] is not null;

-- if the above query returns no rows, then

update [db].[desktop-order-data]
    set ["Web ID"] = cast(["Web ID"] as int);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [range for `int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is:

> -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)

Your `Web ID` numbers are 10 digits long and start with `4` - they're not going to fit.

You might try `bigint` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fit a number on the order of 4363155167 into `int`, which goes from -2147483648 to 2147483647. Can you use `bigint` here?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because there is more than one column in [desktop-order-data] and you are trying to insert only 1 column, without specifying the target column.
Just change your insert statement to:

```
INSERT INTO [db].[desktop-order-data] ([Web ID])
SELECT CAST(["Web ID"] as int)
FROM #tmp
```